# How .on works for $(document)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JS Code does not work for a modal with a form that is loading from an ajax-call to php side.

I think I have to call the function like the following:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#tags', function ()
```

How should I change the original code into this, can someone help and explain it to me?

```js
$('#tags').on({  click: function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 alert('geklickt');},
 mouseenter: function(e) {
  alert('mouse enter!');
 }
});
```

Using only the `$('#tags')` does not work.

Additionally, I have to change this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    bookIndex = 0;

$('#bookForm')

    // Remove button click handler
    .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
        var $row  = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
            index = $row.attr('data-book-index');

        // Remove fields
        $('#bookForm')
            .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="book[' + index + '].title"]'))
            .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="book[' + index + '].isbn"]'))
            .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="book[' + index + '].price"]'));

        // Remove element containing the fields
        $row.remove();
    });
});
```

Which parts do I have to change so the `document.on` support is available?

Comment: It should be `$('#tags').click(function(){ });`

Comment: $('#tags').on('click', function (e) {

Comment: @Loading.. You aren't delegating event here

Comment: @Keith See comment above **⇖⇖⇖**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [pass string selector](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data):

```
$(document).on({
  click: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('geklickt');
  },
  mouseenter: function(e) {
    alert('mouse enter!');
  }
}, '#tags');
```

Comment: How i have to pass the code if i want to add this: 
.on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
            var $row  = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
                index = $row.attr('data-book-index');

            $('#bookForm')
                .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="book[' + index + '].isbn"]'))
                .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="book[' + index + '].price"]'));

            $row.remove();
        });

Comment: This is different selector so there is no really way to make it shorter. Just chain it: `$(document).on(...).on(...)`

Comment: Ok, but how i can work with the "removeButton" in this case "on('click', '.removeButton',", if i have select the "#tags" at least?

Comment: @4usolutions Sorry but i don't understand what you mean? `if i have select the "#tags" at least`? You mean you want to pass both selectors: `$(document).on({...}, '#tags, .removeButton');` or what? You'd have better to provide a concrete sample to make it clearer and even better ask a new question

Comment: i've add some more additional infos in the main topic, hope thats more clear.

Comment: So: `$(document).on('click', '#bookForm .removeButton', function(){...});` but that's still unclear what you are asking?!